# Weird C behaviour

Tags: c

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I don't really know what to call this issue. I'm working on an assignment for a class and I'm getting the strangest error when I try to print out a certain float variable. The program is quite long so I'll just include some snippets:

```
float zero,t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7 = 0.0;
float pzero, pt, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7 = 0.0;
```

The top line variables are total, which are divided by the number of simulations of the program, then dividing the total by the number of simulations I get the probability (last line of variables). When I run my code like this, the output is:

[image]

Since t6 is initialized, the only thing that occurs is it gets bigger, then divided by the simulations, and that value is 100. Just to be sure it wasn't me accidentally changing it I printed t6 out after initializing it and it had a similar value, a very low negative number. Even though it was just initialized to 0. I thought that was weird, but even stranger is when I declare my variables like this:

```
float zero,t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t7 = 0.0;
float t6 = 0.0;
float pzero, pt, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7 = 0.0;
```

The program works absolutely fine, giving me a normal probability. I'm so confused, and I was wondering if anyone knows what is going on here? I can post the full code if necessary but it seems like it's an issue with me declaring it somehow?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Instead of having an absurd number of independent variables, **learn how to use arrays**. These are extremely important for organizing and passing data around. These will make your code much, much easier to work with and bugs like this are less likely to manifest.

Comment: Hint: `float x, y = 0.0` only initializes `y`.

Comment: Simply never write multiple variable declarations on the same line. It leads to bugs and more bugs, for nothing gained.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
float zero,t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7 = 0.0;
```

Only initializes `t7` to 0 and leaves the rest **uninitialized**.  You need to initialize each variable explicitly:

```
float zero = 0, t = 0, t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0, t4 = 0, t5 = 0, t6 = 0, t7 = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare multiple variables with the same value, you have to specify each value `t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0`

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for your comment. I edited the answer to prevent misleading.